# What does this CASE Syntax mean? - VB6

Tags: vb6

I have the following code in the VB6 project I just inherited.

```
Case Is > "S"
Case Is > "Q"
Case Is >= "A"
Case Is = "M"
```

The only one I sort of understand is the Case Is = "M"

What do the ">" (greater than) symbols represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings can be compared with greater than or less than just like numbers can. It should compare their ascii values, basically.

http://www.vbexplorer.com/VBExplorer/Focus/strings_tutorial_2.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: "It should compare their ascii values": whether that is true depends on the value of `Option Compare`; see @Drackir's answer.

Comment: Your second link is for Visual Basic 2005 not Visual Basic 6

Comment: True... but I'm pretty sure that the rules for string equality operators were not changed.

Answer (score 3):

It compares them alphabetically. See the section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) on MSDN entitled "Comparing Strings".

From the docs:

> When you compare strings, the string
>   expressions are evaluated based on
>   their alphabetical sort order, which
>   depends on the Option Compare setting.
>
> Option Compare Binary bases string
>   comparisons on a sort order derived
>   from the internal binary
>   representations of the characters. The
>   sort order is determined by the code
>   page. The following example shows a
>   typical binary sort order.
>
> A < B < E < Z < a < b < e < z < À < Ê
>   < Ø < à < ê < ø
>
> Option Compare Text bases string
>   comparisons on a case-insensitive,
>   textual sort order determined by your
>   application's locale. When you set
>   Option Compare Text and sort the
>   characters in the preceding example,
>   the following text sort order applies:
>
> (A=a) < (À= à) < (B=b) < (E=e) < (Ê=
>   ê) < (Ø = ø) < (Z=z)

Answer (score 1):

Some links from the Visual Basic 6 manual, rather than later versions :)

- [`Select Case` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266274%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)
- [`Option Compare` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266181%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) which controls [string comparisons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212267.aspx)
- [Comparison Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263418%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)